# Unit testing a method that uses configurationmanager in a class library used by a web app

Tags: c#, web-services, testing, configurationmanager

I'm attempting to write a test for the code behind a web service. This code lives in a separate class library called from the service itself. This class library uses `ConfigurationManager` to get its connection strings, normally when you run the web service those are populated by the web service's `web.config`. However, when I run it from my test code they throw `null` exceptions.

I've trolled around the net for answers for a while now and attempted several fixes for roughly similar problems, but nothing worked. (Nothing was exactly my situation.)

Comment: Which unit test framework are you using? You can usually provide a config file that will be made available to the code under test. Of course this requires all test methods in the test assembly to share the same configuration.

Comment: Can you refactor the code in the DLL you're testing for better testability?

Comment: fsimonazzi, I tried something similiar to this, but my code then threw exceptions when my class library tried to grab the connection strings.

Joachim Isaksson, Yes that is ultimately what I was thinking this would boil down to. Trying to figure out the best way to attack this problem. (relocate connection strings, wrappers, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the version of Visual Studio that you have, but if you have VS 2010 you can use [Moles](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/22c07bda-ffc9-479a-9766-bfd6ccacabd4&ei=ZLNvUN-dJJCC8QTJ5oCIBQ&usg=AFQjCNE5vIkcyAjEkCYxdKI5vV7AM3WTVw&sig2=M9sueP3itBi46CA_cH2_3A&cad=rja) to mock static classes and in VS 2012 you have [Microsoft Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx).

Nevertheless, as Joachim Isaksson said in his comment, if you are actually doing a Unit Test, you could wrap access ConfigurationManager to the through an interface and a wrapper, and just mock the interface.

Comment: We just started using VS 2012 (still have to hop back to 2010 for a few older projects but as we hit those items we're bringing them up to speed) I'll have to look into Microsoft Fakes.


I've already done massive refactoring of the project since I started since it was completely untestable before, building out a wrapper and interface wouldn't be unreasonable.


Thank you!


(I would vote you up, but not enough points. Long story short I typically just read, trying to be a good community member and start participating as able)